# Playing audio through javascript and Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio

I am building a website specifically to be accessed via the Chrome browser on an Android device, so it is the only browser I care about to have my code working.

I would like to be able to play a sound upon clicking an object. But as of now, it is SO SO slow to respond and the sound can only keep up if I click on it once every 4 or 5 seconds. I'd like to be able to tap quickly and have the sound keep up.

What is the best way to play audio (wav file) through javascript to get it working well through Chrome on an Android tablet?

I'm currently using `<audio>` tags and then javascript to play the file. (Through the Chrome browser on my computer, it works fine and the speed of the sound is okay. But on the Android tablet the sound painfully lags behind. It's as if the sound isn't being preloaded for some reason, or something like that, on the tablet).

My current code

Right below my `<body>` tag:

```
<audio id="audiotag1" src="ding.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

When the user taps the screen

```
function registerTouch(mouse) {
   play_multi_sound('audiotag1');
}



var channel_max = 3;                                        // number of channels
    audiochannels = new Array();
    for (a=0;a<channel_max;a++) {                                   // prepare the channels
        audiochannels[a] = new Array();
        audiochannels[a]['channel'] = new Audio();                      // create a new audio object
        audiochannels[a]['finished'] = -1;                          // expected end time for this channel
    }

function play_multi_sound(s) {
    for (a=0;a<audiochannels.length;a++) {
        thistime = new Date();
        if (audiochannels[a]['finished'] < thistime.getTime()) {            // is this channel finished?
            audiochannels[a]['finished'] = thistime.getTime() + document.getElementById(s).duration*1000;
            audiochannels[a]['channel'].src = document.getElementById(s).src;
            audiochannels[a]['channel'].load();
            audiochannels[a]['channel'].play();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most mobile browsers don't preload audio/video to save bandwidth.

> The preload attribute is supported in Safari 5.0 and later. Safari on
>   iOS never preloads.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW9

Comment: He said he's using Chrome in Android, not Safari in iOS.